# LinkedIn API without using Oauth

Tags: python, api, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm interested in learning how to use website APIs with python.  I'd like to download and study all my LinkedIn contacts, for example.

Because I'm interested in only my profile for learning purposes, I'd like to avoid the headache of authenticating through Oauth 2.0 and just use my own credentials. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do so without Oauth 2.0
See their Doc;
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/signin-with-linkedin

The package that is usually used with python to make api requests is "Requests"
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/